# How to remove this white background for text in RegionPlot？

Tags: regions, regionplot

In regionplot, How to remove this  white background for text？

[image]

````
 RegionPlot[{q > (\[Phi] \[Mu] c^2)/0.5}, {c, 0, 1}, {q, 0, 1}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"c", "q"}, 
  PlotLabels -> 
   Placed[{Style["L1", 50, Background -> None]}, Center]], {{\[Mu], 
   0.7}, 0.01, 1}, {{\[Phi], 0.3}, 0, 0.5}]```
````

Comment: `Manipulate[RegionPlot[{q > (\[Phi] \[Mu] c^2)/0.5}, {c, 0, 1}, {q, 0, 1}, FrameLabel -> {"c", "q"}, Epilog -> Text[Style["L1", 50], {.5, .55}]], {{\[Mu], 0.7}, 0.01, 1}, {{\[Phi], 0.3}, 0, 0.5}]`

Comment: But I want placed label automaticly.

Comment: Try using `Placed[Style["L1", 50], Center, Background -> None]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest one is to use:

```
Background -> Transparent
```

And the Job Done.

Comment: @kglr - As shown in Carl Woll's comment at the top, the option `Background -> Transparent` or `Background -> None` needs to be used in `Placed` rather than in `Style`. Alternatively, `Background -> Transparent` can be put at the `RegionPlot` level.

Answer (score 3):

```
Manipulate[
 ReplaceAll[f_Framed :> Insert[f, Background -> Opacity[0], 2]] @
  RegionPlot[{q > (ϕ μ c^2)/0.5}, {c, 0, 1}, {q, 0, 1}, 
   FrameLabel -> {"c", "q"}, 
   PlotLabels -> Placed[{Style["L1", 50]}, Center]], 
 {{μ, 0.7}, 0.01, 1}, 
 {{ϕ, 0.3}, 0, 0.5}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

Manipulate[
 RegionPlot[{q > (ϕ μ c^2)/0.5},
   {c, 0, 1}, {q, 0, 1},
   FrameLabel -> {"c", "q"},
   PlotLabels -> Placed[
     Style["L1", 50],
     Center]] /. _Pane?(Not[FreeQ[#, "L1"]] &) :>
   Style["L1", 50],
 {{μ, 0.7}, 0.01, 1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{ϕ, 0.3}, 0, 0.5, 0.005, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 TrackedSymbols :> {μ, ϕ}]
```

[image]